# Selected row's column content copy using clipboard in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

i want to copy the content of a particular column of selected row using clipboard.

i want to execute it with select command in gridview.

Any Help ??

Comment: any code you tried so far? any markup and code behind of your page? any background info so that we can help?

Comment: Explain more. what is your purpose? Do you want to copy it's content in server clipboard or client clipboard?

Comment: I think copy should work as it is no code require or it happens with me